# Uploading maven archetype-catalog.xml into remote artifact repository (Artifactory)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype, archetypes

I have created a new maven archetype(Which is deployed into remote artifact repository as a jar) .

I also have a archetype-catalog.xml file, which i also want to upload to remote artifact repository.

Can anybody help me on doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by manually deploying the catalog via Artifactory GUI.

Comment: How do you fetch this archetype or add your archetype catalog as remove to your settings.xml? I can't seem to figure this out